# Landau notations

Tags: complex-analysis

I am learning about Landau notations, the teacher did the following exercise
$\ln(x+1)\sim x$ by definition it has to $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}=1$.

I don't understand the next step, and I need an explanation about the property that the teacher uses.

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}={\ln(\lim_{x\to 0}(x+1)^{\frac1x})}$

the following steps without simple

${\ln(\lim_{x\to 0}(x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}})}=\ln(e)=1$ therefore $\ln(x+1)\sim x$.

Comment: Hint: $k \ln x = \ln x^k.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}\ln(x+1) = \lim_{x \to 0} \ln(x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}},$$
and then continuity of the function logarithm implies that you can "swap" limit and logarithm to get
$$\ln(\lim_{x \to 0} (x+1)^{\frac1x}).$$